# Windows 7 won't boot. Safe mode stuck at Classpnp.sys after HDD replacement

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, lenovo-laptop

Just replaced the HDD of my Lenovo G570 laptop and having a weird issue. I replaced the old HDD with a new 1 TB HDD. Although I was not sure if the laptop supported 1 TB HDD and couldn't find any relevant information anywhere, I just decided to try. The HDD seemed to be working. I partitioned, formatted, and installed fresh Windows 7 on it. However, Windows now freezes at startup. I reinstalled Windows 7 again and it worked for a few minutes but wont boot again. Tried safe mode. It worked once, but next time didn't (stuck at Classpnp.sys). What may be the issue here? If the HDD wasn't supported it wouldn't have been detected properly,right? But it is detected with correct storage size and everything, so I am guessing the issue is elsewhere?

Comment: We are going to need more information.

Comment: Like? If you elaborate what information is needed, I will try to provide them if I can. Please let me know.

Comment: We will need the BSOD dump for starters.